# How can I sum together calculated values from previous loop iterations?

Tags: ruby

I was wondering If could save and sum up previous values from a previous loop iteration.

So I have this code to loop through an array of grocery items and then sum up how many are being bought of a partciular item. Heres my code.

```
groceries = %w[apples quinoa peppers milk butter]

item = 0

groceries.each do |_i|
  puts 'what groceries are you getting?'
  grocery_choice = gets.chomp

  apples = 2.30
  quinoa = 2.75
  milk = 1.80
  butter = 3.25
  peppers = 3.00

  puts "how many #{grocery_choice} are you getting?"
  number_of_particular_grocery = gets.to_i

  if grocery_choice == 'apples'
    item = apples
  elsif grocery_choice == 'quinoa'
    item = quinoa
  elsif grocery_choice == 'milk'
    item = milk
  elsif  grocery_choice == 'butter'
    item = butter
  elsif  grocery_choice == 'peppers'
    item = peppers
  elsif grocery_choice == 'none'
    break
  end

  total = item * number_of_particular_grocery
  puts "when you buy #{number_of_particular_grocery} #{grocery_choice} it costs #{total}"

  total += total
end

puts " your total grocery bill is #{total.sum { |total, _t| total }}"
```

The last line is broken, but what I am trying to do is essentially

```
total_cost = total_milk + total_butter + total_apples + total_peppers
```

but without explicitly writing it out in the program. Is there a way to save `total` from the previous iteration of the loop and add to the next `total` from the loop iteration after it?

Comment: You should make your life easier by properly indenting your code.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to [so]! In general, it is considered polite to make things as easy as possible when you ask volunteers to donate their free time to you to solve your problems for free. In this particular case, for example, this would include spending a couple of milliseconds to click on the "Format Code" button in your editor instead of forcing (potentially) thousands of answerers to wade through 88 lines of randomly laid out code.

Comment: Yes, just define a var outside of the loop and you can increment it at the end of the loop.

Comment: I would, in my noobish experience with Ruby, reduce the array of grocery items into a hash and reduce the hash into a sum.

Answer (score 1):

I would re-start your problem and consider something like below:

```
GROCERY = {
    apples: 2.30, 
    quinoa: 2.75,
    peppers: 3.00,
    milk: 1.80,
    butter: 3.25
}

def add_grocery_item(bag, item, qty)

    bag.push([item, qty, GROCERY[item]])

end

if __FILE__ == $0

    grocery_bag = []

    add_grocery_item(grocery_bag, :apples, 10)
    add_grocery_item(grocery_bag, :quinoa, 1)
    add_grocery_item(grocery_bag, :milk, 2)
    add_grocery_item(grocery_bag, :butter, 3)
    add_grocery_item(grocery_bag, :apples, 7)
    add_grocery_item(grocery_bag, :quinoa, 6)
    add_grocery_item(grocery_bag, :milk, 6)
    add_grocery_item(grocery_bag, :butter, 9)

    p grocery_bag.reduce(Hash.new(0)){|acc, e| acc[e[0]] += e[1] * e[2]; acc}
end
```

This is just a starting point to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
prices = {
  apples: 2.30,
  quinoai: 2.75,
  milk: 1.80,
  butter: 3.25,
  peppers: 3.00
}

shopping_list = Hash.new(0)

loop do
  puts 'what groceries are you getting?'
  grocery_choice = gets.chomp.to_sym
  break if grocery_choice.empty?

  unless prices.has_key?(grocery_choice)
    puts 'Nope, we do not have that'
    next
  end

  puts "how many #{grocery_choice} are you getting?"
  number_of_particular_grocery = gets.to_i

  shopping_list[grocery_choice] += number_of_particular_grocery
end

total = shopping_list.map { |grocery, quantity| prices[grocery] * quantity }.reduce(:+)
puts " your total grocery bill is #{total}"
```

What I did:

- Combining both your groceries list and price variables into one Hash so that the information is in a single place and updates to the grocery database is easy to perform
- New Hash shopping_list with a default value of 0 will contain the ordered groceries with their quantities
- Endless loop, exits when hitting enter or first question
- The prices Hash allows to detect woring grocery_choice input
- In the end the shopping list is first mapped to an array containing subtotals for each grocery. Then the subtotal array is reduced with the sum operator, effectively calculating the sum of all entries.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are writing it by looping over the groceries does not require user input to select the grocery, you can simply ask how much of each type they are getting and add the price accordingly.

As others have suggested you can sum the cost of each grocery as you were and then add it each time using the accumulator `+=` to a total defined outside of the loop.

As an extra touch you can round your floats to 2 decimal places using `.round(2)`.

I hope this example helps.

```
groceries = %w[apples quinoa peppers milk butter]
total = 0

groceries.each do |grocery_type|
  puts "how many #{grocery_type} are you getting?"
  number_of_particular_grocery = gets.to_i

  if grocery_type == 'apples'
    item_price = 2.30
  elsif grocery_type == 'quinoa'
    item_price = 2.75
  elsif grocery_type == 'milk'
    item_price = 1.80
  elsif  grocery_type == 'butter'
    item_price = 3.25
  elsif  grocery_type == 'peppers'
    item_price = 3.00
  else
    break
  end
  current_grocery_cost = (item_price * number_of_particular_grocery)

  total += current_grocery_cost
  puts "when you buy #{number_of_particular_grocery} #{grocery_type} it costs #{current_grocery_cost}"
end

puts " your total grocery bill is #{total.round(2)}"
```